# How to Sum Each Enum Value in a Different Column and Don't Repeat Person's Name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, enum, sum

Let's say I have a table with `SellerId`, `DateTime`, `ProductType` to register each time a a Seller sells a product. The ProductType is from `ENUM` type with { 0=Phone, 1=Recharge, 2=SimCard }. Then I have a table with `SellerId` and `SellerName`.

I want to write a stored procedure that shows this result:

```
  ID | NAME | Phones | Recharges | SimCards | Total
 ----|------|--------|-----------|----------|-------
  05 | Eddy |      6 |         7 |        0 |    13
```

I know how to `join` the two tables to get the `ID` and `NAME` in this result set, but I do not know how to `SUM` each `ProductType` into a different column. And I also wanted only one row for each `ID/NAME`.

Can anyone show me how to achieve this in this simple example?

Comment: Google for PIVOT command

Comment: I tried to adapt with examples from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query but I could not understand because I did not found examples specific for use with ENUM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple to code using standard SQL if that is what you prefer.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.seller
(SellerID INT,
 SellerName NVARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE dbo.productsold
(SellerID INT,
 SaleDate DATE,
 ProductEnum TINYINT);

-- Sample sellers 
INSERT INTO dbo.seller VALUES (1, 'Frank');
INSERT INTO dbo.seller VALUES (2, 'Sally');
-- Sample transactions
INSERT INTO dbo.productsold VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 0);
INSERT INTO dbo.productsold VALUES (2, GETDATE(), 2);
INSERT INTO dbo.productsold VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 2);
INSERT INTO dbo.productsold VALUES (2, GETDATE(), 0);
INSERT INTO dbo.productsold VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 1);
INSERT INTO dbo.productsold VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 1);
INSERT INTO dbo.productsold VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 0);
INSERT INTO dbo.productsold VALUES (2, GETDATE(), 2);
INSERT INTO dbo.productsold VALUES (2, GETDATE(), 0);

-- Query to pivot and sum
SELECT s.SellerID, s.SellerName,
  SUM (CASE WHEN p.ProductEnum = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Phones,
  SUM (CASE WHEN p.ProductEnum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Recharges,
  SUM (CASE WHEN p.ProductEnum = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SimCards,
  COUNT (p.ProductEnum) AS Total
FROM dbo.seller AS s
   JOIN dbo.productsold AS p ON s.SellerID = p.SellerID
GROUP BY s.SellerID, s.SellerName
ORDER BY s.SellerID;

-- Drop test tables
DROP TABLE dbo.seller;
DROP TABLE dbo.productsold;
```

RESULTS:

```
SellerID  SellerName    Phones  Recharges   SimCards  Total
1         Frank        2        2           1         5
2         Sally        2        0           2         4
```